# Get the React Context from legacy Context API provider implementation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context, legacy

I'm using a [library](https://github.com/trabe/react-conduit) in React, which implements a provider using the [legacy context](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html) API.

This is the implementation:

```js
import { Component, Children } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Registry from "./registry";

class ConduitProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { registry } = this.props;

    this.registry = registry ? registry : new Registry();
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return { registry: this.registry };
  }

  render() {
    return Children.only(this.props.children);
  }
}

ConduitProvider.childContextTypes = {
  registry: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default ConduitProvider;
```

Is there a way to transform the provider into the context you would get with the [nowadays context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) hook in React? The one you'd get by using

```js
const MyContext = React.createContext(defaultValue);
```

I have a component which requires to forward all the contexts used inside and I'm trying to use a different component inside which uses the library.

I already tried wrapping the contents of the component in the `Provider`, but that would not work as the component requires the context.
I also tried to create the context in numerous ways. The most optimistic one was creating a new provider using the `Registry` from the library, but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: I didn't realize by *transform* you didn't mean the code, but instead consume and re-provide. In theory you would just do the below, but your `ConduitProvider` would take the legacy `context` argument as well. Normally it would be a better idea to fork and upgrade the library so you aren't tied to an outdated version of React, but since this feature is native to React ([Portals](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/createPortal)) you don't need a library at all.

---

There isn't much to rewrite for the context itself, but you do have to update all of your children to consume context in the modern way (`useContext` ideally).

```
export const ConduitContext = React.createContext({})

export const ConduitProvider = ({ registry, ...rest }) => {
  const [registry, setRegistry] = useState(registry || new Registry())

  return (
    <ConduitContext.Provider value={registry} {...rest} />
  )
}

export const useRegistry = () => React.useContext(RegistryContext)
```

You would then wrap your components with the provider component:

```
() => (
  <ConduitProvider registry={someValueIfAvailable}>
    {/* Your components */}
  </ConduitProvider>
)
```

Your components would then do something like this:

```
const Foo = () => {
  const registry = useRegistry()

  // ...
}
```